# How to calculate this equation in Python or NumPy loop?

Tags: python, numpy

What is the best way to calculate this in a loop in Python (or NumPy, if you think it is preferred for this kind of operation)?

```
KT = K0[1]*Var0 + K1[1]*Var1 + K2[1]*Var2 + K3[1]*Var3 +
     K0[2]*Var0 + K1[2]*Var1 + K2[2]*Var2 + K3[2]*Var3 +
     ...
     K0[51]*Var0 + K1[51]*Var1 + K2[51]*Var2 + K3[51]*Var3
```

where K0 is an array, containing 51 coefficients (floats). The same for K1, K2 and K3.
Var0, Var1, Var2 and Var3 are constants.

KT is the result, depending on Var0, ... Var3. 
The coefficient arrays are always the same. They do not change.

I'm coming from Fortran, and am currently learning/experimenting with Python, so forgive maybe the novice question. Python loops sometimes behave un-intuitively to me.

Answer (score 1):

Make a `51 X 4` array with your `K`s and a `4 X 1` array with you `X` and multiply. Numpy has something called *broadcasting* that will expand X to be multiplied with every row of K.

```
import numpy as np
K = np.column_stack([k0, k1, k2, k3])
X = np.array([x0, x1, x2, x3])
result = K * X
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Fix Vars as a numpy array[Var0, Var1,..,VarN]
2. Fix K is a numpy array of arrays [[K11, K12,..,K1N][K21, K22,..,K2N],...]
3. Write a lambda function for multiplying Var_row * K_row
4. Vectorize this function using numpy (np.vectorize)
5. Apply vectorized function over data massive (2)
6. Be happy =)

a draft:

```
V_arr = np.array([2, 2, 2, 2])
K_arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],[4, 3, 2, 1],[5, 4, 4, 4]])

def mult_arr(a, b):
   return a * b

mult_vector = np.vectorize(mult_arr)

res = mult_vector(K_arr, V_arr)
```

Comment: Paul, thanks for answering. I'm trying to code this at the moment, but frankly, to me that looks like a terribly overcomplex way of calculating this thing. Setting constants as arrays, setting arrays as arrays-of-arrays, ...
Is there a more intuitive way of doing this thing (something, that will enable someone not familiar with what I'm trying to do, to figure out what way being done, by reading the code afterwards?)

Comment: it's the most numpy-kind approach. with most internal optimisations. it's not very complex in the code, tho. I'll update an answer with a draft

Answer (score 1):

```
num1 = np.multiply(K0, var0) # type: numpy array
num2 = np.multiply(K1, var1)
num3 = np.multiply(K2, var2)
num4 = np.multiply(K3, var3)
# (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) will give a single numpy array and then sum() operation will give you summation of all elemnts
KT = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4).sum()
```